# ssh-add: Error loading key "ECDSA384 key" error in libcrypto

Tags: openssl, fedora, openssh

I'm trying to configure a Fedora Server 38 to communicate through SSH with keyed authentication, i've generated the keys using the `ssh-keygen -t ecdsa -b 384` command and then copied the public key through `ssh-copy-id` to the remote host, and the ssh-add command keeps giving me this error. My sshd and agent are both set to DEBUG3 mode, and the loglines don't give any clue, on the server it completes the key authentication and throws an Authentication failure for user, and on the agent it gives me the 'Error loading key' line.

I've tried copying the ECDSA private key, also tried with RSA. Nothing seems to work. Also, the only auth method enabled is public key, and UsePAM is on. Can anyone give me a clue on this?